# Click a button to change the text of text input

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter

I have this part of code in the Codeigniter controller named 'ajaxcalls' :

```
public function show_contact_persons($client_id) {
        $data['contact_persons'] = $this->common_model->select_records('ci_contact_persons', 'client_id', $client_id);
        //dump($data);

    function echoArray ($array) {
        foreach ($array as $key => $value)
        {
            if ( true == is_array($value) )
            {
               echoArray($value);
            }
            else
            {
                if ($key == 'contact_person_name') {
                    echo '<input type="button" value="'.$value.'" onclick="changeContact(987)" /><br />';
                }
            }
        }
    }
    echoArray($data);

}
```

and then the JS part at the page which is calling the PHP file :

```
function changeContact(contact_name) {
             document.getElementById('contact_person').value = contact_name;
        }
```

I put the number '987' in this example because the code works only with NUMBERS. When I put text inside the bracket, or what I REALLY want to do :

```
onclick="changeContact('.$value.')"
```

then the script doesn't work. ONLY with numbers. What should I change to make it work with strings?

Comment: put quotations around the var you're passing into `changeContact()` otherwise it will render as `changeContact(thisIsUndefined)` which works for an int, but not as a string wihtout quotations because then JS interperates it as a previously defined variable

Answer (score 1):

You are very close.

Use this instead :

```
onclick="changeContact("'.$value.'")"
```

Whats happening is the JS is rendering it as `changeContact(stringValue);` so its expecting it to be a defined variable.

Adding the quotations will pass it into the function as a string which will render as : `changeContact("stringValue");`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `onclick="changeContact(\"'.$value.'\")"` like this or it may cause syntax problem, isnt it?

Comment: @vinayakj `\\` in php is for use with special characters, this shouldn't be necessary but i dont think it could hurt!

Comment: Thank you for the provided solution, which however doesn't seem to work at my side.... I have tried with all the combinations of the quotations. When I put a number inside the bracket (WITHOUT quotes) it works... What about this part :
function changeContact(contact_name) {
    document.getElementById('contact_person').value = contact_name;
  }
????

Comment: @vinayakj thanks pal, I managed to make it work. Your code was correct :)